# Creating NSPredicate based on SQL IN() function for Core Data

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have a scenario where I must fetch multiple records from Core Data based on multiple values of a given column. A common SQL query for this purpose would be

```
SELECT * FROM suppliers 
WHERE supplier_name in ('IBM', 'Hewlett Packard', 'Microsoft');
```

I have not been able to figure out how I'd use the native `IN()` function for this purpose.

The way I am creating the `NSPredicate` at the moment seems redundant and is as follows.

```
NSMutableArray *predicateArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[skus enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *sku, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [predicateArray addObject:
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(AudioSKU == \"%@\")", sku]];
}];

NSString *predicateString = [predicateArray 
                                  componentsJoinedByString:@" OR "];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate 
                                  predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
```

Is there a proper way to use NSPredciate or NSExpression for using `IN` function of SQL? Please enlighten me.

Comment: There is a similar IN operation in NSPredicate as well.

Comment: please be kind enough in pointing out how to use, thank you

Comment: Could someone help reformatting the objective-c code sample to eliminate the horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: I actually found the NYT style guide as a result of this. Good to see an example!

Answer (score 8):

There is a similar feature in `NSPredicate` as well

```
NSArray *skus = @[];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate 
                              predicateWithFormat:@"AudioSKU IN %@",skus];
```

And also you cannot treat the predicate strings like usual strings. You cannot form an array of strings and use them for filtering. If there are multiple joins use the `NSCompoundPredicate`.

A good reference [Using NSPredicate to filter Data](http://www.peterfriese.de/using-nspredicate-to-filter-data/)

Comment: you answer almost killed me of embarrassment, i feel stupid for not trying that...